# How to use a variable to look up in a foreach loop container -ssis?

Tags: sql, ssis

I need to process all the files in a folder.
something like this:

foreach loop over n

```
fileprocess.exe -argument_n filename_n
```

each argument is file specific and will be retrieved from a table.
Need to design ssis package to batch process the files.
foreach loop seems perfect for it.

I'm thinking of using lookup transform to retrieve the corresponding argument.
My question are

- how to feed the variable `@[user::filename]` to the lookup transform?
- how to assign the lookup output into `@[user::argument]`
- Wonder if lookup transform is the right one to use?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Is `fileprocess.exe` an actual executable or are you just trying to demonstrate that you consume the contents of the file? As it reads, you are mixing a Data Flow Component (Lookup Transform) with a Control Flow Task (Foreach Enumerator).

Comment: you are right! lookup transform has nothing to do with control flow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have a table containing columns for file name and corresponding argument, one way to implement your requirement is as below:

1. Add components from below figure to the Control Flow.
2. In the Foreach Loop, Enumerator is set to Foreach File Enumerator. The files are read from a folder, but you could use any type of enumerator.
3. Create 2 variables in the scope of the Loop to hold the file name and arguments, say, **fname** and **farg**. In the Collections tab of Foreach Loop Editor, assign index 0 to the variable **fname**.
4. In the Execute SQL task, write a query to retrieve the arguments for a given filename. Assign variable **fname** as input parameter, set Result Set to Single Row, and assign the result to variable **farg**.
5. In the Execute Process task, pass the variables **fname** and **farg** as arguments for your executable.
   [image: Control Flow Task]

Comment: Thanks a lot! The execute sql task is what I need! Actually I have 2 args: farg1 and farg2. I can get them in one select. Then how to assign both to resultset variable(s)?